# How to remove Images from PDF File?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

**Hello ,thank you for answer my question.This proble is perplex me for a long time.**

I have search this QS for a long time,I read so many article in stack overFlow and google,but those articles is outdated or fragmented,so I have to seek for help.
I hope some one can help me ,please.

```java
public class TEST04 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hi");
        //ori pdf file
        String oriPDFFile = IFileUtils.getDesktopPath().getAbsoluteFile() + "\\1.pdf";
        //out pdf file
        String outPDFFile = IFileUtils.getDesktopPath().getAbsoluteFile() + "\\2.pdf";
        strip(oriPDFFile, outPDFFile);
    }

    //parse
    public static void strip(String pdfFile, String pdfFileOut) throws IOException {
        //load ori pdf file
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFile));
        //get All pages
        List<PDPage> pageList = IterUtil.toList(document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages());

        for (int i = 0; i < pageList.size(); i++) {
            PDPage page = pageList.get(i);
            COSDictionary newDictionary = new COSDictionary(page.getCOSObject());
            PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
            List tokens = parser.getTokens();
            List newTokens = new ArrayList();

            for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++) {
                Object token = tokens.get(j);
                if (token instanceof Operator) {
                    Operator operator = (Operator) token;
                    if (operator.getName().equals("Do")) {
                        COSName cosName = (COSName) newTokens.remove(newTokens.size() - 1);
                        deleteObject(newDictionary, cosName);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                newTokens.add(token);
            }
            PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
            try (OutputStream outputStream = newContents.createOutputStream()) {
                ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(outputStream);
                writer.writeTokens(newTokens);
            }
            page.setContents(newContents);

//            ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(newContents.createOutputStream());
//            writer.writeTokens( newTokens );
//            page.setContents(newContents);
            
            PDResources newResources = new PDResources(newDictionary);
            page.setResources(newResources);

        }
        document.save(pdfFileOut);
        document.close();
    }
    //delete
    public static boolean deleteObject(COSDictionary d, COSName name) {
        for(COSName key : d.keySet()) {
            if( name.equals(key) ) {
                d.removeItem(key);
                return true;
            }
            COSBase object = d.getDictionaryObject(key);
            if(object instanceof COSDictionary) {
                if( deleteObject((COSDictionary)object, name) ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The stack trace:
[image: The error Log]

Answer (score 0):

It works same way like it does in example RemoveAllText.java, just with different tag.

Use code from this example, just use "Do" instead of "Tj".

Of course, if you need to load metadata, etc, you should enumerate and check images threw page resources (like in my example)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Can you give me the detail code?Thank you very much

Comment: RemoveAllText.java is in the source code download.

Comment: I have fond the anwser ,but I copy and change the code,it is doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

*Following the tip in [Ali Yavari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69036488/1729265) you created a test class. Unfortunately that test code produced an exception. This answer focuses on fixing your code.*

According to the stack trace you posted an image of the exception occurred while saving the document; some stream was asked to provide an `InputStream` and it failed with the message "Cannot read while there is an open stream writer".

So, let's have a look where your code opens a stream writer but does not close it again:

```
PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(newContents.createOutputStream());
writer.writeTokens( newTokens );
page.setContents(newContents);
```

Indeed, here you ask a stream (the `PDStream newContents`) for something to write to (`newContents.createOutputStream()`) but don't close it.

You can do that like this:

```java
PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
try (OutputStream outputStream = newContents.createOutputStream()) {
    ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(outputStream);
    writer.writeTokens(newTokens);
}
page.setContents(newContents);
```

---

*A side note*, you will have to re-write what you do with the `newDictionary` object. Currently you

1. initialize it with the page dictionary entries,
2. recursively remove all entries with a key that is a name of an image you remove, and
3. set the page resources to this dictionary.

Item 2 can delete much more than you actually want, the same name in a different dictionary may refer to an entry with a completely different meaning. Furthermore, you recurse without further checks; if there is a circular relation among the dictionaries, this may result in an infinite recursion, i.e. a stack overflow exception.

Item 3 sets this manipulated page clone inappropriately as the resources of the original page. This create a completely broken page structure.

Instead you should retrieve the resources from the page (`resources = page.getResources()`) and remove the images by putting them to `null` (`resources.put(cosName, (PDXObject)null)`).

Comment: Hey mkl,thank you very much ,I have changed my code ,it is no error,but the outPDFFile'page is empty.the ori pdf file is 3 pages,and the out pdf file is also 3 pages,but every page is empty.so i don't know what's wrong ,can you give me a completely code to delete images form page? thank you very much.

Comment: *"I have changed my code"* - how have you changed it? Did you also consider what i wrote under the horizontal rule? How have you fixed your manipulation of the resources?

Comment: Hello ,thanks for help.I have update my question code by your ieda,it's no error,but also empty,so can you gei me some code ...to fix it.

Comment: @Colin *"I have update my question code by your ieda,it's no error,but also empty,so can you gei me some code ...to fix it."* - Have you read the side note in my answer underneath the horizontal rule? That side note explains why your code create a completely broken page structure and how to change it...

Comment: I saw this:" you should retrieve the resources from the page (resources = page.getResources()) and remove the images by putting them to null (resources.put(cosName,(PDXObject)null)).",But you know ,I can't understand your note,because,the ori class is copy from others,I don't know PDFBox well,so beg you give me a completely code .In fact,i just need remove specified images,they have a cosName,just like img7,img8 ,so ,can you tell me how to fix my code

Comment: Hey mkl, i Found you have answered so many qs in stackvoerflow about pdfBox how to remove images,but there is no one can copy direct and use,you give us some note ,but I don't know how to fix....so can you give some completely code that can directly worked?thank you very much. And I also want to know ,how to use cosName to remove images

Comment: @Colin *"so can you give some completely code that can directly worked?"* - Does my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69424735/1729265) suffice? *"And I also want to know ,how to use cosName to remove images"* - See the end of this answer, *retrieve the resources from the page (`resources = page.getResources()`) and remove the images by putting them to `null` (`resources.put(cosName, (PDXObject)null)`).*

Answer (score 0):

*In [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69250666/1729265) I focused on advise on how to fix the code in the question. Here I focus on a different approach to the task.*

In your code you try to remove the bitmap images by inspecting the page content streams, finding **Do** operations therein drawing XObjects, and removing both this instruction and the referenced XObject.

It is a bit easier to instead simply *replace all image XObjects* in the resources by an empty form XObject. This is the approach used here.

As that approach is very easy to implement, I extended it to not only go through the immediate resources of the pages but also iterate into embedded form XObjects and patterns.

```java
void replaceBitmapImagesResources(PDDocument document) throws IOException {
    PDFormXObject pdFormXObject = new PDFormXObject(document);
    pdFormXObject.setBBox(new PDRectangle(1, 1));
    for (PDPage pdPage : document.getPages()) {
        replaceBitmapImagesResources(pdPage.getResources(), pdFormXObject);
    }
}

void replaceBitmapImagesResources(PDResources resources, PDFormXObject formXObject) throws IOException {
    if (resources == null)
        return;

    for (COSName cosName : resources.getPatternNames()) {
        PDAbstractPattern pdAbstractPattern = resources.getPattern(cosName);
        if (pdAbstractPattern instanceof PDTilingPattern) {
            PDTilingPattern pdTilingPattern = (PDTilingPattern) pdAbstractPattern;
            replaceBitmapImagesResources(pdTilingPattern.getResources(), formXObject);
        }
    }

    List<COSName> xobjectsToReplace = new ArrayList<>();
    for (COSName cosName : resources.getXObjectNames()) {
        PDXObject pdxObject = resources.getXObject(cosName);
        if (pdxObject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
            xobjectsToReplace.add(cosName);
        } else if (pdxObject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
            PDFormXObject pdFormXObject = (PDFormXObject) pdxObject;
            replaceBitmapImagesResources(pdFormXObject.getResources(), formXObject);
        }
    }

    for (COSName cosName : xobjectsToReplace) {
        resources.put(cosName, formXObject);
    }
}
```

*([RemoveImages](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/RemoveImages.java#L76) helper methods)*

To apply this approach to a `PDDocument` simply call the first `replaceBitmapImagesResources` with that document as parameter.

Beware: I tried to keep the code simple; for production use remember to limit the recursion here to prevent endless recursions as in some PDFs XObjects or patterns call themselves directly or indirectly. Also you may want to inspect page annotations and the resources of template pages.